# Python Bokeh CustomJS RadioGroup

Tags: javascript, python, charts, bokeh, dashboard

I'm reasonably experienced with Python and Pandas, but very new to the Bokeh package and have been struggling with this task for the last couple days without progress. I'm building a dashboard to display data, and it would be very helpful to use radio buttons to select/show different lines on the same plot. I've been following the example from here (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3715) which I can get to work fine using the checkboxes. I've changed the "CheckboxGroup" to a "RadioGroup" in line 21, as well as the "active" argument. The result is that both plotted lines disappear when I change the selection of the radio buttons and never come back. I don't understand why the CheckboxGroup works and the RadioGroup doesn't, considering how similar they are and that they both use the "active" event for callback. Could somebody please point out my mistake?

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, RadioGroup
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(3*np.pi*t)
c = np.cos(3*np.pi*t)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(t=t, s=s, c=c))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
a = plot.line('t', 's', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, 
line_color='blue')
b = plot.line('t', 'c', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6,
line_color='red')

checkbox = RadioGroup(labels=["Cosinus", "Sinus"], active=0)

checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(line0=a, line1=b), code="""   
    //console.log(cb_obj.active);
    line0.visible = false;
    line1.visible = false;
    for (i in cb_obj.active) {
        //console.log(cb_obj.active[i]);
        if (cb_obj.active[i] == 0) {
            line0.visible = true;
        } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 1) {
            line1.visible = true;
        }
    }
""")

layout = row(plot, widgetbox(checkbox))

show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In radioboxgroup, you can only have one active value at once so your for loop is useless as you try looping over an integer. Here is your code corrected

```
checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(line0=a, line1=b), code="""   
    line0.visible = false;
    line1.visible = false;

    if (cb_obj.active == 0) {
        line0.visible = true;
    } else if (cb_obj.active == 1) {
        line1.visible = true;
    }
""")
```

There is a better way to do this, if you have many lines you can use the length of the "labels" list in a loop

```
line_list = [line0,line1];

lab_len=cb_obj.labels.length;

for (i=0;i<lab_len;i++) {
if (cb_obj.active == i) {
line_list[i].visible = true;
} else {
line_list[i].visible = false;
}
}
```

In a checkboxgroup the "active" attribute is a list of indices. You just have to change the if condition to make the code work:

```
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Cosinus", "Sinus"], active=[0,1])

checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(line0=a, line1=b), code="""   
    line_list = [line0,line1];

    lab_len=cb_obj.labels.length;

    for (i=0;i<lab_len;i++) {
    if (cb_obj.active.includes(i)) {
    line_list[i].visible = true;
    } else {
    line_list[i].visible = false;
    }
    }
""")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to plot this using the multi_line method. Then you can chose which line(s) are selected on a callback as shown below.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, RadioGroup
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(3*np.pi*t)
c = np.cos(3*np.pi*t)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(t=[t]*2, s=[s,c], colors = ['red', 'blue']))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.multi_line('t', 's',line_color='colors' ,source=source)

checkbox = RadioGroup(labels=["Cosinus", "Sinus"], active=0)

checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s=source), code="""   
    s.selected['1d'].indices = [cb_obj.active]
    s.trigger('change');
""")

layout = row(plot, widgetbox(checkbox))

show(layout)
```

Comment: I like this compactness, and I'll have to use it in the next dashboard. I've been using pandas DataFrames (or slices thereof) in Bokeh, but I see the ColumnDataSource in a lot of places. Is it worth it to put the relevant data from a DF in a ColumnDataSource and then plot that instead of using the DF directly?

Comment: Well the key reason ColumnDataSources and other data source objects are used is because they are required for most levels of interactivity and dynamic updating. To update or change plots with a dataframe you most likely have to end up recreating the entire plot each time. 
In my expierence so far I have just found it easier to stay with ColumnDataSource, and if I want data from a DF simply just use the to_dict method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to let users easily control the visibility of glyphs, then as of Bokeh `0.12.5` you can have legends be interactive, to either hide glyphs or mute them, when user clicks on a legend entry:

[image]

If you want to completely hide glyphs, set a legend's `click_policy` to `"hide"`:

```
p = figure()
p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6], legend="foo")
p.square([1,2,3], [7,9,8], legend="bar")
p.legend.click_policy = "hide"
```

You can also set a policy to mute:

```
p.legend.click_policy = "mute"
```

But you will need to specify what the "muted" appearance looks like for each glyph, e.g.

```
p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6], muted_alpha=0.2, legend="foo")
```